# Is there a setting to stop the display of "No data available in table" in the DataTable?

Tags: javascript, html, datatable, datatables

Initially my table has no data and I get "No data available in table" which is the expected functionality.

I'd like to have no text or row created as I will be populating the table via Ajax depending on user action.

Is there a setting to stop the display of this row in the table? I can't seem to find one. This code works but the first row reads "No data available in table". This is the jQuery code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/Home/postInformationofConferenceTitle',
    dataType: "JSON",
    success: function (data) {

        $.post("/Home/selectRooms", { xtitle: data.xglobalTitle }, function (data) {

            var ndx = 0;
            $.each(data.xroom_name, function (key, value) {

                var Xroom_name = data.xroom_name[ndx];
                var Xroom_plan = data.xroom_plan[ndx];

                var column =
                  ('<tr>' +
                    '<td>' +
                    '<div class="img-container">' +
                    '<img src="../../assets/img/room-plan/' + Xroom_plan + '" alt="..." id="imgsrc">' +
                    '</div>' +
                    '</td>' +
                    '<td id="imgname">' + Xroom_name + '</td>' +
                    '<td class="text-right">' +
                    '<a href="#" class="btn btn-simple btn-warning btn-icon edit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>' +
                    '<a href="#" class="btn btn-simple btn-danger btn-icon remove" ><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>' +
                    '</td>' +
                    '</tr>');

                document.getElementById('colmn').innerHTML = document.getElementById('colmn').innerHTML + column;

                ndx++;

            });

        });

    }
})
```

Comment: When you send an empty array to dataTables API, It will automatically returns "No Data Is Available". Is this not happening ?

Comment: it is happening. I said that "Is there a setting to stop the display of this row in the table? I can't seem to find one."

Comment: If you want you can remove that text from `dataTables.min.js` but when you have an empty array just remove the first row of that table(inside tbody)  using jquery instead of changing the source file. can you just show what you have tried

Comment: I updated my question . You can look there

Comment: I just want to remove the "No data available in table" text that appears when there is no data in the database. Because first row always reads "No data available in table".

Comment: So you want it to display just empty?

Comment: Yes I want something just like this

Comment: Added an answer. Please check if that is what you are looking for

Comment: @Engr.Arda Before $.each function set empty html document.getElementById('colmn').innerHTML = "";

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works for me.

```
var someTableDT = $("#some-table").on("draw.dt", function () {
    $(this).find(".dataTables_empty").parents('tbody').empty();
}).DataTable(/*init object*/);
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. When answering a question that already has an accepted answer, please be sure to add some additional insight into why the response you're providing is substantive and not simply echoing what's already been vetted by the original poster. 
This is especially important in "code-only" answers such as the one you've provided.

Answer (score 11):

I guess you might be looking at the language settings of datatables.

```
language : {
        "zeroRecords": " "             
    },
```

(Note the space between " ". (Its a hack but found it to be useful for now.)

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

 var serverData = [
 ]
 var table = $('#example').DataTable({
   language : {
            "zeroRecords": " "             
        },
  data: serverData,
  columns: [
   { data: "name" },
   { data: "age" },
   { data: "isActive" },
   { data: "friends" },
  ],
  'columnDefs': [{
   'targets': 2,
   'render': function (data, type, full, meta) {
    let checked = ''
    if (data) {
     return '<input type="checkbox" checked / >';
    }
    else {
     return '<input type="checkbox"  / >';
    }
    return data;
   }
  },
  {
   'targets': 3,
   "render": function (data, type, full, meta) {
    var selectInitial = "<select>";
        var selectClosing = "</select>";
        var options = '';
    $.each(data, function (key, value) {
     options = options+"<option value="+value.id+">"+value.name+"</option>";
    });
    return selectInitial+options+selectClosing;
   }
  }
  ],
 });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src='https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js'></script><link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/css/jquery.dataTables.css'>

<table id="example" class="display" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>name</th>
                <th>age</th>
                <th>isActive</th>
                <th>friends</th>
                 
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
```

Comment: This worked, but this time the delete and update buttons on the table does not function when clicked. What can I do for this

Comment: When you dont have data, you will not get delete/update buttons right?

Comment: serverData is an variable in my example. You need to appropriately modify it to suit your example. You need to just take language object

Comment: Can you drop your email address or skype so I can get support from you.

Comment: I know I am very late. Checking if there is anything I can help?

Answer (score 1):

Below worked for me:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#TABLE_ID").DataTable();      
        $(".dataTables_empty").empty();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Next CSS worked for me to totally hide that block (not only delete text):

```
.dataTables_empty
{
    display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#table').dataTable({
    //initialization params as usual
    fnInitComplete: function () {
        if ($(this).find(".dataTables_empty").length == 1) {
            $(this).parent().hide();
        }
    }
});
```

This will hide only in that case when there is no data.