# How to redraw a Datatable before injecting values via JavaScript

Tags: datatables

I would like to have a table to keep a history of the uploaded files

[Here is a dummy example of what I did so far](http://live.datatables.net/vepedopa/32/)

Whenever I update the table injecting some values via JS, the row with the text `No data available in table` still appears.

[image]

I've tried the solutions provided in [other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49269837/is-there-a-setting-to-stop-the-display-of-no-data-available-in-table-in-the-da) but none of them worked for me

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Instead of appending the `<tr><td>` you must use the [datatables rows.add() api](https://datatables.net/reference/api/rows.add())

Comment: Could you provide an example to mark your answer as valid? I don't know how to hook it up altogether.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because your datatable object is unaware of the changes that were made in DOM. You need to use the [datatables rows.add() api](https://datatables.net/reference/api/rows.add()) instead of appending `<tr><td>` to your table.

Please modify your javascript as below. Notice the use of `DT1.row.add` inside your `$.each` instead of `$('#nameBody').append` :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#fileholder').change(function(e){
            var files = $('#fileholder').prop("files")
            var names = $.map(files, function(val) { return val.name; });
            var modDates = $.map(files, function(val) { return val.lastModifiedDate; });
            $.each(names, function(index){
              DT1.row.add([names[index], modDates[index]]).draw();
            });
        });
    
    var DT1 = $('#names').DataTable({
        columnDefs: [
            { className: 'text-center', targets: [1] },
        ],
        order: [
            [1, 'asc']
        ],
        dom: 'rt'
    });
});
```

Comment: Woah thank you so much that was it!